# jenkins ssh plugin deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

I'm using the jenkins with ssh plugin for my CI deployment, the question is:
 I configure 2 servers (e.g A, B) to be deployed, however , only the first server(A) is completed the deployment, if I change the order(B, A), then only the B server is completed the deployment.I'm confused by this. any one can help me?

Comment: Do you use 2 Jenkin jobs and run SSH for A and B separately?

Comment: I use one job to run SSH plugin and add server A and server B

Comment: Interesting, I tried SSH plugin, but only allow to use one SSH server.

Comment: @wbinglee  yeah.that's what I'm confused about.

Comment: I think you can configure multiple servers in the system configuration. But each Jenkin job you will only to use one SSH server to run script. If you need to run in two servers, you will need to create two jenkin jobs. You may use other plugin which can trigger other job after first job is done.

Comment: Is your servers running Unix or what?